# Code copied from one file to another will not build

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have some code that sets a border around a UITextView.  It builds correctly in one class; when I take that code and copy it to another class (changing the object name), it no longer builds, saying "Property 'borderWidth' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer *'" (the same message for the other two lines of code).  I have done a clean, re-build and nothing helps.  Why is this happening?  and how do I fix it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {
[super viewDidLoad];

//--  draw box around notes field
orderNotes.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
orderNotes.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
orderNotes.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

}

Object "orderNotes" is defined as UITextView.  There are no other errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Otherwise, the `layer` property is not visible to you.

Comment: I can not believe I missed that!  (show me with lot's of egg on my face!)  Thank you so much...